# add #*# glob to .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to add emacs autosave files to my .gitignore with the glob `#*#` but of course, lines starting with a hash are comment lines.

How can I get this into my .gitignore without it being treated as a comment?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Did you try

```
\#*#
```

Or:

```
\#*\#
```

Since 1.6.2, `\` should be supported in `.gitignore` (see [this patch](http://osdir.com/ml/git/2009-02/msg01285.html))

To be precise, [1.6.2.1](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.6.2.1.txt#L7-L8) (March 2009)

> `.gitignore` learned to handle backslash as a quoting mechanism for comment introduction character "`#`".

Comment: I have restore the dead link 1.6.2.1

Comment: I found I needed to escape both occurrences: `\#*\#`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you for your feedback. I have included this second option in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 33):

Another way of escaping `#` is to use the character set syntax, so that your `#*#` glob becomes

```
 [#]*[#]
```

in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 8):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but I think it may solve more problems than just this one symptom:

You can [move the autosave and backup files](http://amitp.blogspot.com/2007/03/emacs-move-autosave-and-backup-files.html) into a completely different directory so that your source directories don't get cluttered.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

```
*[#]*[#]
*[#]*
```

@CharlesStewart was close but did not work for sub-directory files which had autosave generated files.